# HTTP 303 redirection and robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot, 303-redirect

On a site I'm working on, we're using the HTTP 303 redirect pattern (see [this article for background](http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/168)) to distinguish between information and non-information resources. So: some URL's under `/id` get redirected to dynamically-created pages under `/doc`. These dynamic pages are built from a database, and contain links to other `/doc/` resources, so in general we don't want them to be crawled. Our *robots.txt* contains:

```
Disallow: /doc
```

However, we do want the non-redirected pages under `/id` to get indexed by Google et al:

```
Allow: /id
```

So the question I have, which I can't find an answer to so far, is: if an allowed `/id` page 303-redirects to a `/doc` page, will it still be blocked by *robots.txt*?

If yes, we're OK, but otherwise I'm going to disallow all `/id` resources in the robots file, as having the crawler hammer the db would be worse than losing search indexing for the `/id` pages.

Comment: Is it possible to make the database-generated pages under /doc/ be put at /id/ rather? That way, you can index what you want, and block what you don't want public. I don't see 303 as a good idea, though: http://sharkseo.com/nohat/303-redirects-seo/

Comment: The whole point of separating /doc and /id is *so* that they are different. This allows you to make the distinction between information *about* a thing and a reference to the thing itself. As for user agents not recognising 303 redirects, that hasn't proved to be a problem in practice, and a primary aim anyway is to support machine processing of semantic web resources.

Answer (score 2):

> So the question I have, which I can't find an answer to so far, is: if
>   an allowed `/id` page 303-redirects to a `/doc` page, will it still be
>   blocked by *robots.txt*?

From a crawlbot or search engine that obeys *robots.txt*: **Yes**.

If I put a link to `your.com/id` or `your.com/doc` on my own website, Google will crawl it, follow redirect, read your *robots.txt* and disallow it from being indexed.